# Flutter-Desktop sqflite ffi throwing error on release mode

Tags: dart, ffi, sqflite, flutter-desktop, dart-ffi

I am using [sqflite ffi](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi) for my database on desktop windows.
I setup everything like in the sample. The application is working on debug built but if I run the application on release mode I'm getting the error in `sqfliteFfiInit()`. How can I fix that?

```
Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library (126)
```

```
Future<void> init() async {
  try {
    sqfliteFfiInit();
    
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());  
  }
  _databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;

   String path = '${await _databaseFactory.getDatabasesPath()}\\myDB.db';
   _db = await _databaseFactory.openDatabase(path);

   final List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await _db.query(
     'sqlite_master',
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: <String>['MyDB'],
    );

    if(result.isEmpty){
      await _db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE MyDB (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
)
''');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sqflite ffi github page says:

"In release mode, add [sqlite3.dll](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/raw/master/sqflite_common_ffi/lib/src/windows/sqlite3.dll) in same folder as your executable."

Comment: This works fine. But what about exporting using MSIX? In that we can not place under windows apps folder.

Comment: I added that file as the Github page says, still getting "FileSystemException: Cannot open file", whereas it's working fine in debug mode... any idea?

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out how to make this work in release mode when generating an MSIX package for Windows?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Hey it seems you found a solution for the msix package. I saw it here: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/945#issuecomment-1515310817 Thanks.